# Passing form values from one page to another

Tags: php, html, forms, get

In my form I am trying to pass `acad_id` to `academy_view.php` page.  After the form submits I am trying to append  `acad_id` to the url. In this way I can use `GET` in `academy_view.php` to pull up the records from mysql db. But everytime after submission the post url has an empty field for id.

academy_create.php

```
$acad_id = $_POST['acad_id'];
<form action="academy_view.php?id=<?php echo $acad_id; ?>" method="POST">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"></br>
        Academy ID: <input type="text" id="acad_id" name="acad_id"></br>
<input value="SAVE" name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

academy_view.php

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0){
                 // query db
            $acad_id = $_GET['id'];

//Some Code

}
```

After submitting the URL shows id empty: http://www.example.com/academy_view.php?id=

Comment: You are submitting acat_id twice, as GET parameter and as form value of POST. Use just POST with hidden field: `<input type="hidden" id="acad_id" name="acad_id" value="$acad_id" />`

Comment: @erny how do i retrive `$acad_id` from `academy_view.php`?

Comment: You are posting from "academy_create.php" to "academy_view.php", so it  would be `$acad_id = $_POST['acad_id'];`. if you don't bother, use the $_REQUEST variable instead of $_GET and $_POST.

Comment: @erny Alright, I am a little lost but I am following you somewhat. Would you mind posting an official an answer please

Comment: Added. I hope it's understandable. You transport state from one page to another by adding something to URLs or adding inputs (hidden or not) to a form with the values of past user provided data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit you code to use POST as follows

```
<form action="academy_view.php" method="POST">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"></br>
    Academy ID: <input type="text" id="acad_id" name="id"></br>
<input value="SAVE" name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

And

```
if (isset($_POST['id']) && is_numeric($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] > 0){
             // query db
        $acad_id = $_POST['id'];

//Some Code

}
```

Comment: POST doesn't hide anything, it's easily viewable in the header. Use POST when you don't want something bookmarkable(like a form save) or the contents are to big to fit in the GET. It offers no security.

Comment: I am still not getting anything passed to the `academy_view.php`

Comment: did you change the `name` of Academy ID field in the html code?(code fragment 1)

Answer (score 0):

The way to transport values (state) from one page to another is through request parameters, e.g.:

- URL, like GET parameters
- Request body, like form POSTs.

Suppose you are in `academy_create.php` and have already the request parameter (GET or POST) `acad_id`, i.e. URL = 'http://example.com/academy_create.php?acad_id=1' or as form field, you could do the following if don't want the user to fill out "acad_id" (it's already determined):

```
...
$acad_id = $_REQUEST['acad_id'];
...    
<form action="academy_view.php" method="POST">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name"></br>
  Academy ID: <input type="hidden" id="acad_id" name="acad_id" value="$acad_id"></br>
<input value="SAVE" name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

If you want the value to be changeable by the user, just change "hidden" to "text".

If you want the value to be readonly, set add the `readonly` to the input.

Now, in `academy_view.php` you can get the value again with:

```
$acad_id = $_REQUEST['acad_id'];
```